# Filehandling file path

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-file

Basically i have two questions. i am using the below code to read and write z text file.

```
    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
    myFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                            new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    myOutWriter.append("my text here");
    myOutWriter.close();
```

this create a new file every time i want this to OPEN_OR_CREATE(if file already exist don't create a new one)

Ad my second question is that how to change the path "/sdcard/mysdfile.txt" i want this file to stored in my sdcard -> subFolder1 -> SubFolder2

Thnaks

Comment: start by reading the documentation of the methods you are using and of the ones next to the ones you are using. you'll find some of your objects constructors have very explicit variations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use hardcoded `/sdcard` or `/mnt/sdcard` or your app will fail as devices vary on location or mountpoint of that storage. To get the right location use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

See [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

To append content to existing file use `new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);` instead of just `new FileOutputStream(myFile);` - see [docs on that constructor here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29).

As for

> how to change the path "/sdcard/mysdfile.txt"

Aside from getting rid of `/sdcard` as said above, just add subfolders to the paths: `MyFolder1/MyFolder2/mysdfile.txt`. Note these folder have to exists or the path will be invalid. You can always create it by calling `myFile.mkdirs()`.

Comment: Thanks for Answer, The first works really great. But the Writing file problem always write at the end of file. i want the old text to be replaced with the new one.

Comment: wasn't it what you wanted -> *"if file already exist don't create a new one"* - this is what it does. It do not re-create the file, hence appending to old content.

Comment: O yes yes yes Got it; and working fine now. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
```

with

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true); //true means append mode.
```

Appart from that I have one suggestion for you.

Never never hardcode `/sdcard` in code,Rather consider writing.

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"mysdfile.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer, but this always write at the end of file. i want the old text to be replaced with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution to write to end of text file

```
private void writeFile (String str){
      try {
          File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),"tasklist.txt");
          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);

          fw.write(str+"\n");
          fw.flush();
          fw.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
}
```

*File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"your/pth/here","tasklist.txt");

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File f = new File(dir+"/subFolder1/",xyz.txt); <-- HOW TO USE SUB FOLDER

if(file.exists())
{
     // code to APPEND
}
else
{
     // code to write new one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1> OPEN_OR_CREATE
You can try or can replace MODE_APPEND with true like @Vipul's suggestion

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(your_path_file, MODE_APPEND);

//it means if the file is exist the content you want write will append into it.
```

2> stored in my sdcard -> subFolder1 -> SubFolder2

you can use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() to get full file path the SDCard. Then concat strings to get the file path you want. Ex:

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = "myFile.txt";

File f = new File(baseDir + File.separator  + subfolder1 + File.separator +  subfoler2, fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 we can do it this way:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
BufferedWriter wrt = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```